# cgi - stop reading input

Tags: linux, timer, cgi

I've tried to represent mouse movement on via cgi-script.
tried this:

```
file=fopen(MOUSEFILE, "r"); 
while((fread( &ie, sizeof(struct input_event),1,file)==0) && (i<1000)){i++;} 
fclose(file);

if(i==1000){
  printf("<IMG SRC=\"../images/mouse.bmp\">"); 
}else{
  if(ie.type==2 && ie.code==0 && ie.value==-1){
    printf("<IMG SRC=\"../images/left.bmp\"");
  }else if(ie.type==2 && ie.code==0 && ie.value==1){
    printf("<IMG SRC=\"../images/right.bmp\"");
  }else if(ie.type==1 && ie.code==272 && ie.value==1){
    printf("<IMG SRC=\"../images/pressed.bmp\">");
  }
}
```

works fine if the mouse is moved or something is going on, but if mouse is inactive the page dies by waiting on fread. How can I stop executing fread after 500ms - 1s???
or how can i get a workaround???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
file = open(MOUSEFILE, O_RDONLY | O_NDELAY);
while(  (1>read(file, &ie, sizeof(struct input_event))) && (i<50000)  ){i++;}
close(file);
if(i==50000){
  printf("<IMG SRC=\"../images/mouse.bmp\">"); 
}else{ ...
```

**O_NDELAY** doesn't care if the file is ready and aborts the read after the first try.
so the code tries *50000* times and exits the **while** after that